# How can I make my <TableSection> look like that on the Apple iOS Settings page with an icon on the left?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a settings page code and a custom renderer like below but what I would like to be able to do is to make a text cell with an icon on the left like Apple have on their Settings page.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

```
<ContentPage.Content>
   <StackLayout>
      <TableView Intent="Settings" RowHeight="50" HasUnevenRows="true">
         <TableView.Root>
            <TableSection>
               <TextCell Text="English" StyleId="disclosure" Tapped="ABC"/>

            </TableSection>
```

```
            </TableSection>
        </TableView.Root>
      </TableView>
    </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
```

I already set up this:

```
public class TextCellCustomRenderer : TextCellRenderer
{
    CellTableViewCell cell;
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var textCell = (TextCell)item;
        var fullName = item.GetType().FullName;
        cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(fullName) as CellTableViewCell;

        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new CellTableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, fullName);
        }
        else
        {
            cell.Cell.PropertyChanged -= cell.HandlePropertyChanged;
            //cell.Cell.PropertyChanged -= Current_PropertyChanged;
        }

        cell.Cell = textCell;
        textCell.PropertyChanged += cell.HandlePropertyChanged;
        cell.PropertyChanged = this.HandlePropertyChanged;
        cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        cell.TextLabel.Text = textCell.Text;
        cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = textCell.Detail;
        cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        switch (item.StyleId)
        {
            case "checkmark":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
                break;
            case "detail-button":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailButton;
                break;
            case "detail-disclosure-button":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
                break;
            case "disclosure":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
                break;
            case "none":
            default:
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
                break;
        }

        //UpdateBackground(cell, item);

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tables/add_a_cell_accessory/

Comment: Or you can use ImageCell and add accessory https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18131/listview-cell-arrow-disclosure-indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/viewcell/).

**ViewCellRenderer** is more appropriate.

In that project, you just need to place the image left of the text, the code in the class **NativeiOSCell** and method **LayoutSubviews**

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
{
    base.LayoutSubviews();

    SubheadingLabel.Frame = new CGRect(100, 18, 100, 20);
    CellImageView.Frame = new CGRect(5, 4, 33, 33);
}
```

**PS**:

- If you want to change the text, modify the **GetList** in **DataSource**
- If you want to change the image content, replace those images in the folder **CustomRenderer.iOS/Resources/Images**

This is my test

[image]